# Digital visible Sign with pdfbox 1.8.8

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I'm using pdfbox 1.8.8 to generate Visible sign on PDF.
Here is my code. I'm not able to get visible Sign in pdf.
All I get is a rectangle box having no content.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(temp);
        document.getCurrentAccessPermission().setCanModify(false);
        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("XyZ");
        signature.setLocation("XYZ");
        signature.setReason("test");
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        
        InputStream image = new FileInputStream("download.png");
        
        PDVisibleSignDesigner signatureDesigner = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(
                document, image, document.getNumberOfPages());
        signatureDesigner.xAxis(0).yAxis(0).zoom(-80).signatureFieldName("signature");

        PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();
        signatureProperties.signerName("Xyz").signerLocation("Xyz")
                .signatureReason("Test").preferredSize(100).page(1)                    
       .visualSignEnabled(true).setPdVisibleSignature(signatureDesigner).buildSignature();

        SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
        options.setVisualSignature(signatureProperties);

        document.addSignature(signature, (SignatureInterface) this, options);

        /* Sign */
        document.saveIncremental(tempIn, tempOut);
```

Actual Result :

[image]

Expected Result :  I want this block with the Image and signature field content.

Comment: 1.8 supports only jpeg images (the example)

Comment: Thanks Tilman Hausherr :)

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Btw it is better to use PDFBox 2.0.*, that one is more flexible, and has an additional example for visual signing.

Comment: Yes. By replacing the .png file to .jpeg file, It shows the only image, not text. For text also I might move to the 2.0.* version of PDFbox. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: I'm using PDFBox version 2.0.9 along with bcpkix-jdk15on version 1.60 but not able to find the addSigner method of  CMSSignedDataGenerator class. Any idea?

Comment: It's addSignerInfoGenerator(). You need to use the sign() code from the example there. The current version is 2.0.21. The sign() code is in CreateSignatureBase.java in the source code download or https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignatureBase.java?view=markup

Comment: I tried with the above method and it's working fine but not able to display SIgnature Text.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006001/digital-signature-with-pdfbox-2-0-9
This is ref link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in 1.8.* supports only JPEG files.

I recommend to use the 2.0.* PDFBox version, there are two examples of digital signing (including one with text), and they are more flexible and offer more features.